# SVG image shows weird shadows after compiled by React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a svg image that contains some shadows on several elements and it works nicely in a django project. I now included that in my react.js project and it suddenly drops weird shadows. Why's that and where to fix this in react?

```
// Landing.js

import Body from './Body'
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../assets/images/illu_how.svg'
import React from "react";

import './Landing.css'

function Landing(props) {
    return (
        <Body>
        <div className="image-wrapper animate__animated animate__fadeInRight"><Logo classname="illu_how" /></div>
</Body>
```

[JS fiddle due to SO character limitation](https://jsfiddle.net/5kq89z1L/)

React.js project:

[image]
[image]

Django project:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share your SVG content and related imported styles.

Comment: Please try to make a snippet with your SVG.

Comment: @SMAKSS I added it but removed some paths due to character limitation

Comment: The SVG that you provide looks ok, there were some closing group tags issues, but still could not reproduce your issue. I created a snippet with your SVG (the one with fixed closing tags) please add the removed element from it, then maybe we can locate the problem.

Comment: @SMAKSS thanks for the support, I added a fiddle since SO only let me insert 35.000 characters. The fiddle shows the desired output, but once built by React.js it throws the shadows

Comment: Thanks, but still can't reproduce it as expected. I guess the problem lays behind the extra classes that you used over the element, try to remove them one by one and see what happens.

Comment: In the fiddle, the `xlinkHref` property of `<use>` and `<image>` tags should be replaced with `xlink:href` to see the shadows.

Comment: Can you show what happened to the `<use>` and `<image>` elements in the output (in the inspector in the browser)?

Comment: @qrsngky I added it, it seems that the shadows are coming from the nested use statements under `boxes`

Comment: @Jonas Did you also load another SVG tag that contains sub-elements of id="_Image1" or id_="Image2"?

Comment: @qrsngky hm no, for now I just deleted the `<use>` tags in the svg file which seems to work... not sure why react struggled here :(

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even have to be another SVG element. Any other DOM element with the same ids, when copied into the same page, can interfere with `href`.

Comment: i only have one component in my app so far, so I can definitely say theres not :( ... now I dont have the shadows anymore though

Comment: @qrsngky I added both results React.js and Django both with the snapshot and the rendered html. I cant see any difference in the code... hm

Comment: @Jonas Since the codes for the `<use>` look normal, it looks like something happens to the referenced elements (the elements with id="_Image1" and id="_Image2"). What is the result of entering `document.querySelector('#_Image1')`?

Comment: `null` when I console.log it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally... the issue was the import

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from '../../assets/images/illu_how.svg'
```

that caused the shadow problem for whatever reason.

This works just fine:

```
import illustration from '../../assets/images/illu_how.svg'
```

Comment: Now I am wondering if it is a webpack issue.